# Can't Create a Javascript Blob with Edge in Internet Explorer" mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, blob

I am trying to do a download using a Javascript Blob. Creating the Blob is failing silently. As an example,

```js
var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
```

If I surround it in a try catch block and do an alert on the error name and message, I get `TypeError` that `'Blob' is undefined`. We are running pretty old JavaScript and I am wondering if I need a specific JavaScript version to support `Blob`. I cant seem to find any info on `Blob` version support with regard to Edge running in I.E. mode.

Comment: Are you executing this in the browser, or in a Node context?

Comment: Those are some confusingly uneven brackets you have there. I imagine both of your `]` are meant to be `}` (Though, the first parameter doesn't need brackets of any sort? Or you are missing a key for that object)

Comment: "Blob Constructor" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#browser_compatibility tells you which version of browser you need.

Comment: Nice catch on the bracket problem. i have edited my post with the correct code. I am looking at the webpage for Browser types that support Blob. I am running Edge in I.E. mode. I don't see I.E. being supported, but Edge is. Does that mean Blob is not supported because i am running in I.E. mode ?

Comment: It is quite possible (probably, even) that Edge's IE mode does not implement any new web APIs that weren't supported in IE.  You're going to want to do your research specific to that context, and make certain your questions very clearly explain that context and provide the appropriate tags.

Comment: I contacted Microsoft support and here is what I got: Q: Hi, Coding a file download ion Javascript and using a Blob. Info on Blob ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#browser_compatibility ) says it is compatible with Edge. Doesnt list Internet Explorer. I am using Edge in Internet Explorer mode. Should it support Blob creation ?
A: From what I just went through in Microsoft forums,it seems like IE does support Javascript. But I have read that there are bugs when viewing sites that support javascript.   So much for a definitive answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to download the file using the Blob if I took Edge out of Internet Explorer mode. That leads me to believe that Javascript Blob is not supported in I.E. mode. (Not good news for the legacy app I support...). Thank You one and all for your answers !